# Why my jaxb2marshaller does not unmarshal what it marshalled before?

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

Im struggling with the jaxb2marshaller configuration to work with classes generated from wsdl file.

My jaxb2marshaller

```
 public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
    final Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPaths("org.otheruri", "org.tempuri");
    return marshaller;
  }
```

I prepare a structure of classes and pass them thru marshaller.marshal to get the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:ValidateResponse xmlns="http://otheruri.org" xmlns:ns2="http://tempuri.org/">
<ns2:ValidateResult>
<ArrayOfPerson>
<Person><NawNumber>personNAW</NawNumber></Person>
</ArrayOfPerson>
</ns2:ValidateResult>
</ns2:ValidateResponse>
```

But when I take this xml and run marshaller.unmarshall the ValidateResult.arrayOfPerson is null. There is no stacktrace or anything.

My generated classes look like this

```
package org.tempuri

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "validateResult"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ValidateResponse")

    public class ValidateResponse {

        @XmlElementRef(name = "ValidateResult", namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
        protected JAXBElement<org.otheruri.ValidateResponse> validateResult;

        public JAXBElement<org.otheruri.ValidateResponse> getValidateResult() {
            return validateResult;
        }

        public void setValidateResult(JAXBElement<org.otheruri.ValidateResponse> value) {
            this.validateResult = value;
        }

}
```

and

```
package org.otheruri

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ValidateResponse", propOrder = {
    "persons",
    "userLoggedIn"
})
public class ValidateResponse {

    @XmlElementRef(name = "Persons", namespace = "http://otheruri.org", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<ArrayOfPerson> persons;
    @XmlElementRef(name = "UserLoggedIn", namespace = "http://otheruri.org", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<ValidateCredentialsResponse> userLoggedIn;


    public JAXBElement<ArrayOfPerson> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    public void setPersons(JAXBElement<ArrayOfPerson> value) {
        this.persons = value;
    }

    public JAXBElement<ValidateCredentialsResponse> getUserLoggedIn() {
        return userLoggedIn;
    }

    public void setUserLoggedIn(JAXBElement<ValidateCredentialsResponse> value) {
        this.userLoggedIn = value;
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

So after time and lots of debbuging I know what is wrong. For unknown reason the created xml has ArrayOfPerson node (like class name) instead of Persons (that is specified in @XmlElementRef). Still I dont know why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end it appeared that my generated object factory had 2 methods that returned same JaxbObject and accepted ArrayOfPerson object and very similar name, but had different name specified in the @XmlElementDecl, and of course I used the wrong one to generate xml, so I could not consume it later. :/